# Python : Subtract 1 month from date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, relativedelta

I want subtract 1 month from a date. I'm using `relativedelta` but this subtract 6 months.

```
print('the max date : ' , all_data['DT_ANO'].max())
dt_start = all_data['DT_ANO'].max() - relativedelta(month = 1)
print('dt_start : ' , dt_start)
```

I get this result  :

```
the max date :  2021-08-16 00:00:00
dt_start :  2021-01-16 00:00:00
```

instead of :

```
the max date :  2021-08-16 00:00:00
dt_start :  2021-07-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: I think you should be using `datetime.timedelta` rather than `dateutil.relativedelta`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing that relativedelta is a dateutil function, then use

```
relativedelta(months=1)
```

If you use month, year, day, ... the value will be absolute, if you use month**s**, day**s**, year**s**, the value will be relative.